# A messy "users" situation with SSH uploads, Apache and Tomcat processes

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am in a messy situation that involves Apache and Tomcat 6. I serve PHP projects with Apache.

I use Tomcat to run Solr, a RESTful interface for search. I place the **Solr index within the PHP application**. This is helpful as all the code and data associated with a project is stored in a single directory. And it works without a hitch in our Windows development machines.

---

But it gets tricky in my Linode Ubuntu VPS. I log in as **root** using SSH and all files I write in that session are owned by **root**. But then,

1. all PHP directories need to be readable and writable by **www-data**, which Apache runs as.
2. the Solr indexes need to readable and writable by **tomcat6**, which Tomcat runs as.

Hence, my flow to deploy a new project:

1. Log in as **root** with SSH and copy files to www
2. use chown to make the project owned by **www-data**
3. use chown to make the Solr index subdirectory owned by **tomcat6**

---

The obvious way to make this straightforward is to create a new user **xx**, and run Apache and Tomcat as **xx** and upload to SSH as **xx**. What is a good solution so that I can simply upload the files so that both Apache and Tomcat can use it straightaway without any further settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put www-data and tomcat6 in the same group and add your user (or root) to that group.
`sg` and `umask` so files you copy get the correct group and are g+rw.

Comment: After making the group make the www folder group sticky. This along with the common group and umask will make it very easy to manage the permissions.